# Oauth issue while authorizing the request token for linkedIn integration in iOS

Tags: ios, ios6, oauth, linkedin-api, access-token

Am developing a sample app to integrate LinkedIn API for sharing post. Using external library https://github.com/pmilanez/MIS-Linkedin-Share .Given correct APIKey and secrete Key provided by the LinkedIn.But while authorizing the request token am getting response like this

-oauth_problem=timestamp_refused&oauth_acceptable_timestamps=1384430277%2B-900

So my question is,what is this response means and how to resolve it .
Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: Is any one got the solution of this ??

Comment: @MayuriRTalaviya i have fixed this issue.Time stamp is depended on clock on your os.Previously i havent given tick mark on "set time and date automatically" in Date & Time prefreneces.oath will work according to timestamp,so after ticking that option ,it works fine :)